# foreach statement rewrite last element?

Tags: php, foreach

Im using foreach as below

```
 foreach($album as $a) { 

$string .= $a['value'].', ';

 }

 echo $string;
```

which returns something like

```
  1, 2, 3,
```

etc

now how do I remove the , from the last loop.

So $string returns 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$values = array();
foreach ($album as $a){
  $values[] = $a['value'];
}

$string = implode(',', $values);
```

Comment: wouldn't you consider the other keys of `$album`? it may be an array due to iteration and using `$a['value']`

Comment: Not if it's a nested array as $a['album'] seems to indicate

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
$value = array();
foreach($album as $a) { 
    array_push($value, $a['value']);
 }

echo join(',', $value); // join by comma
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to do this

```
rtrim($string, ',');
echo $string;
```

should do the job.

Comment: end() returns the last key, not true or false, so that method would not work

Comment: @Mahn Well spotted, thanks! Hadn't used it for a while and it was a bit off the top of my head. Answer updated.

Comment: Hm it's still not quite right, now you are comparing a key with the array itself. If OP were to do foreach($album as $key => $a) you could theoretically compare end($album) to $key. In practice though, end() not only returns the last key but also resets the internal pointer of the array — and messing around with the internal pointer is a bad idea if the code is within a for loop such as foreach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = TRUE;
$string = '';
foreach($album as $a) {  
    if ($first) {
        $first = FALSE;
    } else {
        $string .= ', ';
    }
    $string .= $a['value']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop would be better suited in this case, so that you could just avoid adding it for the last element.

But you can just trim the string to the right.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `implode()`, which is the best method, you can create a temp var:

```
foreach($album as $a){ 
    $string .= $addStr . $a['value'];
    $addStr = ',';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$string = preg_replace('#, $#', '', $string);
```

Comment: No. This might answer the question, but don't fix the symptoms; fix the cause. `implode()` the array rather than looping it, and you won't need to worry about a trailing comma.

Answer (score -1):

**Easiest way:**

```
foreach($album as $a){ 
    $string .= $a['value'].', ';
}

$string = substr($string, 0, -2);
echo $string;
```

More on substr [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Why the downvote? It works well on cases where implode cannot be used (which is not the case of OP, but it remains a good alternative)